# Make elements show above carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have a carousel, using owlCarousel, and I'm trying to make the elements in the carousel to expand on hover. The way it's implemented, is it's simply `displayed: none` by default, then on hover, it's displayed to block. Nothing fancy.

It's taken out of the flow by an absolute positioning, this way the carousel will not expand on element hover.

The problem is, when the element get's hovered, the details, expanded element doesn't show. I tried giving it a high `z-index`, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Here's the code:

[CodePen FIle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPvzXP)

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.owl-carousel {
  background-color: orange;
}

.owl-carousel .item:hover .details {
  display: block;
}

.owl-carousel .item-inner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.owl-carousel h4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}

.owl-carousel .details {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>1</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>2</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>3</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>4</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>5</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>6</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>7</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>8</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>9</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>10</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>11</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>12</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this will work for you:

1. Set `.owl-carousel .item` to your `content height + detail height` (I used 200px)
2. Set `margin-top` of `.owl-carousel.owl-theme .owl-nav` to `-(detail height) + 10px` (it was originally `10px`)

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.owl-carousel {
  background-color: orange;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
  height: 200px;
}

.owl-carousel .item:hover .details {
  display: block;
}

.owl-carousel .item-inner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.owl-carousel h4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}

.owl-carousel .details {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-theme .owl-nav {
  margin-top: -90px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>1</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>2</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>3</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>4</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>5</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>6</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>7</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>8</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>9</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>10</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>11</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>12</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! Great answer! Don't know how you came up with that! Can you just explain to me the margin thing?

Comment: it's to adjust the nav controls back to where they would be without the extra item height

Answer (score 0):

You can try not giving a top value, and instead a height of auto to `.details`

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.owl-carousel {
  background-color: orange;
}

.owl-carousel .item:hover .details {
  display: block;
}

.owl-carousel .item-inner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.owl-carousel h4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}

.owl-carousel .details {
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>1</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>2</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>3</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>4</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>5</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>6</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>7</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>8</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>9</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>10</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>11</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
      <h4>12</h4>
      <div class="details">
        This is some crazy cool details that you will have to know about
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I want the yellow to show as well, and the pink to display right under the yellow.